# error in assigning classes to values from a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, logical-operators

[image: Sample of the data being entered as CSV sheet]

```
coupe=data.frame(read.csv(file.choose()))

#UNITS AS PER GIRTH - I want to assign girth classes to each tree for further computation of value


coupe$g.class = NA

for (i in 1:(nrow(coupe))) {
  if (coupe$girth[i] < 60) {
    coupe$g.class[i] = 0.25
  } else if (coupe$girth[i] < 89) {
    coupe$g.class[i] = 0.5
  } else if (coupe$girth[i] < 119) {
    coupe$g.class[i] = 1
  } else if (coupe$girth[i] < 149) {
    coupe$g.class[i] = 2
  } else if (coupe$girth[i] < 179) {
    coupe$g.class[i] = 4
  } else if (coupe$girth[i] < Inf) {
    coupe$g.class[i] = 6
  }
}
```

Compiling this code gives me the error
Error in if (coupe$girth[i] < 60) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Any leads on what I am doing wrong? This same block ofcode compiled perfectly on another dataset (different coupe) but isn't doing so for the one I am working with presently

Comment: Try [`cut`](https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/base/html/cut.html).

Comment: I need to add the value individually as a separate column, so cut is not the most ideal here I am guessing. If I needed how many are in which range, cut would be perfect.

Comment: You may get better, faster help if you edit your question to be reproducible. Good luck!

Comment: There's no obvious error in the code - your error could occur if `nrow(coupe)` is zero due to a problem reading in your data. I'd suggest checking that, and if that's not it, you'll need to add the output of `dput(coupe)` to your question to help people answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your desired `g.class` values aren't in a specific pattern, you could use `findInterval` to make your cuts, then recode them to your desired values.

If you didnt mind your variable being a factor, you could simply do:

```
df$g.class_fact <- factor(findInterval(df$girth, c(60, 89, 119, 149, 179)),
                          labels = c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6))

#    species girth quality g.class_fact
# 1      sal   159       N            4
# 2      sal   179       N            6
# 3      sal    14       N         0.25
# 4      sal   195       N            6
# 5      sal   170       N            4
# 6      sal    50       N         0.25
```

If you wanted them as a numeric values, just wrap that in `as.numeric(as.character(...))`:

```
df$g.class_fact <- as.numeric(as.character(factor(findInterval(df$girth, c(60, 89, 119, 149, 179)),
                          labels = c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6))))
```

You could also do it by `match`ing on a reference dataframe (here I created two variables, `g.class` and `g.class_ref`, just for comparison, but can overwrite instead)

```
# reference values 
ref_values <- data.frame(interval = 0:5, newvals = c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6))

df$g.class <- findInterval(df$girth, c(60, 89, 119, 149, 179))
# > df$g.class
#  [1] 4 5 0 5 4 0 2 0 5 5 4 2 2 5 5 2 3 2 1 0

df$g.class_ref <- ref_values$newvals[match(df$g.class, ref_values$interval)]
```

Output:

```
#    species girth quality g.class    g.class_ref
# 1      sal   159       N       4           4.00
# 2      sal   179       N       5           6.00
# 3      sal    14       N       0           0.25
# 4      sal   195       N       5           6.00
# 5      sal   170       N       4           4.00
# 6      sal    50       N       0           0.25
# 7      sal   118       N       2           1.00
# ...
```

And for a `tidyverse` approach, you could also use `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::case_when` to recode the values if you didn't want to create a reference data frame/use `match`:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, g.class_dplyr = dplyr::case_when(
  g.class == 0 ~ 0.25,
  g.class == 1 ~ 0.5,
  g.class %in% 2:3 ~ g.class - 1,
  g.class == 4 ~ g.class,
  g.class == 5 ~ 6
))

#    species girth quality g.class g.class_ref g.class_dplyr
# 1      sal   159       N       4        4.00          4.00
# 2      sal   179       N       5        6.00          6.00
# 3      sal    14       N       0        0.25          0.25
# 4      sal   195       N       5        6.00          6.00
# 5      sal   170       N       4        4.00          4.00
# ...
```

Data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(species = "sal",
                 girth = sample(1:200, 20),
                 quality = "N")
```